# Efficient patterns to inject per case handlers in a "loop template"

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, macros, metaprogramming

Here's what I would like to achieve in pseudo code:

```
void apply(Range r, CompOp op, LessCase less, SameCase same, MoreCase more) {
  for (auto item : r) switch (op(item)) {
    case Less: less();
    case Same: same();
    case More: more();
  }
}
```

Option 1 - a macro - albeit the most archaic option many would frown upon, seems like a good fit, especially in light of enabling to inject statements in the context of the function, such as `break` or `return` statements.

Option 2 - a template function with capturing lambda expressions - this will capture the external context, so if I need to fall through or early abort, it would take extra steps to facilitate that.

Option n - something else?

"Best" is quite subjective, my top priority is performance, and I also value simple, obvious and readable ahead of bleeding edge complexity. I am not discouraging such answers, as other users might find them useful, simply clarifying.

Which also excludes any signal / slot or dynamic dispatch or runtime implementations, performance mandates compile time only.

Comment: Option 0: Just write out the loop and switch/case every time? Unless your "loop template" is more complicated, but even then you have to pass some code for each case, so you might as well make it a switch/case

Comment: @Artyer and write in assembly while at it, no? I was under the impression that reusability and clarity are good things. I an working on an architecture I have to do an exceeding amount of those, and they are far more easier and manageable than to just write it all out, and then struggle if I need to make changes...

Comment: There are in fact a bunch of templates and interopable prefab handlers for them, used in various combinations, it would be outright insanity to do this the the boilerplate way. Composition is tremendously faster, easier and safer. Reducing one-pagers to one liners that basically contain the sequence of words describing what happens... how is raw boilerplate better?

Comment: Option 0b: code generation. You can have your fancy DSL and compile it to dumb C++.

Comment: @Botje care to suggest any domain specific languages suited for development of domain specific languages?

Comment: Python and Ruby are nice, but whatever language you are comfortable in.